# Postgres failback after failover

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, failover

We are using streaming replication in a Postgres v10 system. We have managed to get the failover from Primary to Standby to work correctly, but we cannot work out how to failback to the original setup.

Our setup may be a bit unusual, as each server is in a different data-center. Failover consists of not only moving the primary database to a different data-center, but the associated client applications. So due to speed/bandwidth reasons it is important that after a failover we can revert (failback) to our normal configuration.

Our setup is as follows:

```
Primary1  ----replicate---> Standby1 ---replicate---> HotStandby2
```

As stated we can kill the master and failover to the following situation

```
Standby1 ---replicate---> HotStandby2
```

We now would like to failback, so we build a new database called Primary2 and set it as a replication of Standby1

```
Standby1 ---replicate---> HotStandby2  
         ---replicate---> Primary2
```

After a while Primary2 is in sync with Standby1, so we would like to promote Primary2 to be a active server, and then reconfigure Standby2 to be a replication of Primary2 to get back to the original state

```
Primary2  ----replicate---> Standby1 ---replicate---> HotStandby2
```

It is easy to promote Primary2 to be active, but we cannot find any way of moving Standby2 from an active to standby state.

We have tried

1. insuring that Primary2 is in sync with Standby1
2. Changing the recover.done to recover.conf
3. adding recovery_target_timeline = 'latest' to the recover.conf
4. Setting up new replication slots
5. Using pg_rewind
6. Using pg_rewind along with archive WAR files

Most of our attempts result in Standby1 still running as a master and some strange messages in the logs files about diverging timelines....

Has anyone have any ideas or can point us to some articles - tutorials, etc.

Is this even possible in Postgres? Or should we then rebuild Standby1 and if so what about HotStandby2?